# MonoDoc: Installing and adding http://iosapi.xamarin.com/

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios

I noticed on a recent video from Miguel that he was accessing MonoDoc with the contents of http://iosapi.xamarin.com

Is there an install location for MonoDoc (there doesn't seem to be one at http://www.mono-project.com/Documentation that works) that allows us to add http://iosapi.xamarin.com/ to MonoDoc?

Pressing help in MonoDevelop does not seem to open anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have submitted a bug fix request to Xamarin and will update this when it is completed.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13243758/132599), I had to run `/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/MonoDoc.app/Contents/MacOS/macdoc` in Terminal in order for the *Help* menu item to start working in MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

MonoTouch installs the documentation for MonoDoc to use.   You do not need to do anything, except hit Help from MonoDevelop

Comment: I have the Enterprise MonoTouch license with the newest MonoDevelop, but when I select the help menu item nothing happens. Is there something I need to enable to get the documentation? (P.S. I found your Enya-Monotouch-Cat video helpful, please record more if you have time)

Comment: Odd, that is part of MonoDevelop.   What version of MonoDevelop are you using?

Comment: MonoDevelop 3.0.3.5, Mono 2.10.9, Monotouch: 5.2.12, Mac OS X 10.7.4, Human 1.0.1

Comment: Did you select the **Help** menu item under the **Help** menu ? the **Search** item comes from OSX and won't let you find anything from MT.

Comment: Me too. I've been asking a question over here http://stackoverflow.com/q/13242106/132599 about context sensitive help in MonoDevelop. Very confused when trying to follow the answer provided and nothing happens.