# Context sensitive SDK help in MonoDevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

When I'm using Visual Studio, I can press the F1 function key when the cursor is on a method and the associated MSDN documentation for that method will be displayed. I'm currently developing an iPhone application using MonoDevelop/MonoTouch and it would be really useful to be able to do the same thing. Does MonoDevelop provide this functionality or do I need to use my browser to search for the SDK documentation? I've googled and the only reference I've found to this behaviour is to press Command-Quote which does nothing on my system. Is there an alternative that provides a better experience?

Comment: AFAIK, MD doesn't have this feature.  Xamarin has a [UserVoice](http://xamarin.uservoice.com/) channel for submitting suggestions and feature/enhancement requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, however the shortcut on Mac is Cmd-Opt-? (i.e. Cmd-Opt-Shift-/ on US keyboard). You can rebind it to another key if you want in the preferences dialog.

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit dense but this isn't working for me. I've tried Cmd-Opt-Shift-/ with the cursor on e.g. _UITableViewCellAccessory_ and I can see the _Help_ menu item flash blue and then nothing. Can you please provide an example or reference material for how this is supposed to work.

Comment: It might be that the item is not resolved. If the menu is flashing blue then it sounds like the command is being activated fine.

Comment: Any chance you can give me a for instance? I'm still not sure what it is I'm supposed to be seeing. I've tried putting the cursor on a bunch of different methods/classes and still nothing.

Comment: Does the MonoDoc app open when you run the menu command directly?

Comment: Um no actually, where can I find MonoDoc?

Comment: Hmmm, just found this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/q/11834620/132599 which will hopefully shed some light. Looks like my MonoDoc is broken.

Comment: What output do you get if you run `/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/MonoDoc.app/Contents/MacOS/macdoc` from a terminal?

Comment: Cool, that brings up the Mono Documentation Browser. And now the shortcut keys in MonoDevelop are working. That's awesome thank you for your help.

Comment: Wow, that's strange. No idea how it wasn't working until you manually ran that :/

Comment: The same steps resolved it for me too. Thanks David and @mhutch.